# DefaultHttpClient is deprecated in Scala

Tags: scala, web-scraping, jsoup, httpclient, ldjson

I am trying to hit an external API (authentication required) with LD-Json data from another URL. Not getting how to add key and password for that external API. Tried to use DefaultHttpClient, but it's deprecated.

**First approach-**

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.util.Base64

import org.apache.http.auth.{AuthScope, UsernamePasswordCredentials}
import org.apache.http.client.methods.{HttpGet, HttpPost}
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
import org.apache.http.impl.client.{BasicCredentialsProvider, DefaultHttpClient, HttpClientBuilder}
import org.jsoup.Jsoup

class Scraper(url: String) {
  def getJson(url: String) = {
    val doc = Jsoup.parse(url)
    val api_url = "external_api"
    val username = "my_username"
    val password = "my_password"
    val ldJsons = doc.select("script[type=\"application/ld+json\"]")
    val base64EncodedDoc = Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(doc.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))

    val post = new HttpPost(api_url)
    post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(base64EncodedDoc))
    val response = (new DefaultHttpClient).execute(post)
//need an alternative for this in Scala
  }
}
```

**Second approach-**

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.util.Base64

import org.apache.http.auth.{AuthScope, UsernamePasswordCredentials}
import org.apache.http.client.methods.{HttpGet, HttpPost}
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
import org.apache.http.impl.client.{BasicCredentialsProvider, DefaultHttpClient, HttpClientBuilder}
import org.jsoup.Jsoup

class Scraper(url: String) {
  def getJson(url: String) = {
    val doc = Jsoup.parse(url)
    val api_url = "external_api"
    val username = "my_username"
    val password = "my_password"
    val ldJsons = doc.select("script[type=\"application/ld+json\"]")
    val base64EncodedDoc = Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(doc.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    val credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider()
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
      AuthScope.ANY,
      new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password)
    )

    val httpClient =
      HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
        .build()

    val httpResponse = new HttpGet(api_url)
    httpResponse.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
    httpClient.execute(httpResponse)
//how to pass my LD-Json data here?
  }
}
```

This is my first question here. If it's too trivial, please excuse me. I am trying to write a scraper class in Scala, which fetches LD-Json from a URL and posts that to an external API.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [HttpClientBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html).

Simple example:

```java
String url = "http://example.com";

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

System.out.println("Result: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me how would you do Post with the LD-Json data?